# как дебажить React приложения

Tags: reactjs

У меня возник вопрос, как правильно дебажить react, вот поставил я деббагер здесь

```
  debugger
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {posts.length && posts.map(item => (
        <Post key={item.id} title={item.title} body={item.body} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

нажимаю f10 спускаюсь вниз и дальше улетаю на кучу других файлов в которых вообще не мой код, понятное дело, что это код реакта и он типа тоже выполняется "под капотом", но мне то зачем это видеть, почему я должен надимать раз 20 f10, переходя по вкладками типа: react-dom-development, atoms.js, playback.js... что это и зачем мне это и как это скипнуть, да и ещё такое момент, вот хочу я посмотреть что сейчас лежит в title={item.title} или непосредственно в item, но я не могу этого сделать, если я навожу курсор на item он ничего не показывает, как это вообще работает, вы все с этим живете или я один чего-то не знаю?

Comment: Если еще не ставил то установи React Developer Tools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=ru

Comment: да он у меня есть, ну всм он устанволен в браузер, надеюсь я так все понимаю, у меня 2 вкладки появились Components and Profiler, я так понимаю нужно там как-то дебажить? я пока их вообще не открываю и в учебных проектах тоже ни разу не видел, чтобы ими кто-то пользовался

Comment: во вкладке components ты можешь выбрать компонент свой и посмотреть все пропсы и стэйт

Comment: о, ок, спасибо ..

Answer (score 1):

[@LevShportak](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/310619/lev-shportak):

Если еще не ставил то установи [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=ru)

Во вкладке components ты можешь выбрать компонент свой и посмотреть все пропсы и стэйт